# FirebaseAuth does not print realtime data in the membership creation step

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have created a membership system in my application. I create record with Firebase Auth and store some information in firebase realtime . However, I saw that 1% of the users did not print their data to firebase realtime during record creation. If users' data is not written to firebase realtime, my application will crash. I haven't been able to figure out how to fix this problem for weeks.
I would be glad if you help.
The table where I store user information: users

Regard.

This my code;

```
    private void signUp(){

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        writeNewUser(user.getUid(), email);
                 
                    }
                }
            });

}


    private void writeNewUser(String userId, String email) {
    Long duration = Constants.TRIAL_DAY_MILI;
    if (MyApplication.getInstance().getmServer() != null) {
        server serverTime = MyApplication.getInstance().getmServer();
        long unix_seconds = serverTime.Time;
        Date date = new Date(unix_seconds);
        SimpleDateFormat jdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String java_date = jdf.format(date);
        Integer review = 0;
        boolean subscriptions = false;
        long expiredTime = serverTime.Time + duration;
        User user = new User("User", email,
                1L, messagingToken, deviceId, expiredTime, membership, memberStatus, playerUid, languagename, durum, java_date, subscriptions, review);
        Device device = new Device(messagingToken, deviceId);

        MyApplication.getInstance().setUser(user);
        mDatabase.child("userdeviceid").child(userId).setValue(device);
        mDatabase.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                startActivity(new Intent(StartServer.this, MainActivity.class));
                saveIsLoggedIn(true);
                finish();
            }
        });
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.signerror), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartServer.this, StartServer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say anything concrete about the cause without knowing how those 1% users are different from the other 99%.

One step that might help in troubleshooting is to first [detect whether the client is connected to the database backend](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state) before writing to the database. While observing this `.info/connected` node won't change anything about the behavior, it might allow you to see if the connection state makes any difference for who is experiencing the problems.

You'll need another place to log data for folks who are not connected to the database, so consider logging both the connection state and the completion of the write to something like Google Analytics, or some other location that is not dependent on the database itself.

Comment: I think the problem here is

The Auth process is completed during the user registration process, but the user closes the application before the realtime process is completed. How can I force this action? I want to prevent the subscription from being created without printing Firebase Realtime.

Comment: You can [use an auth state listener](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android) to pick up the user sign-in when they restart the app. Then try to read their profile from the database, and if you don't get any results for their UID, ask the to register again.